# Creating checkerboard pattern

Tags: java, algorithm

I have to write a Java method called Checkers that accepts two integer parameters and uses these values to print a checkerboard pattern of hash tag symbols.  For example, the values 3 and 4 would result in the following output:

```
          # #
           # #
          # #
```

I'm not sure of how to create this method beyond creating the parameters of the method.  I suspect the simplest way would be to create two for loops, but I'm not sure as to how I would write them.

Comment: What's the relationship between 3 and 4, and the output you gave. Is 3 the number of lines? What is 4? Anyway, if you think using two for loops is the right way, then give it a try. I'm sure your Java text book explains how for loops work.

Comment: 3 would be the number of rows, 4 would be the number of columns.

Comment: Then define "column". I see only two hashtags on each row, and the rows don't star at the same column for some unknown reason.

Comment: @user3410845 I've edited my answer to propose a O(n) algorithm, which you might find interesting.

Answer (score 1):

#### Thinking out of the box

```
 |#O#O#O#O|#                #O#O#O#O
#|O#O#O#O#|                 O#O#O#O#
 |#O#O#O#O|#       =>       #O#O#O#O 
#|O#O#O#O#|                 O#O#O#O#  
 |#O#O#O#O|#                #O#O#O#O
```

1. Build the patterns `#O#O#O#O` and `O#O#O#O#` once and for all.
2. Draw either `#O#O#O#O` or `O#O#O#O#` `height` times.

---

```
public static void printCheckerBoard(int height, int width) {
    // build patterns
    String pn1 = "";
    String pn2 = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        if (j % 2 == 0) {
            pn1 += '#';
            pn2 += '0';
        } else {
            pn1 += '0';
            pn2 += '#';
        }
    }
    // draw rows
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        System.out.println(i % 2 == 0 ? pn1 : pn2);      
    }
}
```

[O(n)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Linear_time)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having boolean flags, here is a simple logic for your problem: just print a `#` char for every cell that has both even/odd rows and columns else print a space.

(Odd rownum and Even column num) and (Even rownum and Odd column name) prints space.

(Even rownum and Even column num) and (Odd rownum and Odd column name) prints hash.

```
class abcd
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        printCheckerBoard(3,4);
        printCheckerBoard(5,6);
    }
    public static void printCheckerBoard(int rows, int cols)
    {
        System.out.println("Rows: "+rows+" and Columns: "+cols);
        for(int i=1;i<=rows;i++)
        {
            System.out.print("\t");
            for(int j=1;j<=cols;j++)
                if((i%2==1 && j%2==1) || (i%2==0 && j%2==0))
                    System.out.print("#");
                else
                    System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ javac abcd.java 
$ java abcd 
Rows: 3 and Columns: 4
    # # 
     # #
    # # 
----------------------------
Rows: 5 and Columns: 6
    # # # 
     # # #
    # # # 
     # # #
    # # # 
----------------------------
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Saw the question was already answered but figured I would give it a try.

```
public class checkers {

public static void checker(int rows, int columns){

    boolean odd = false;

    for(int y=1; y<=rows; y++){
        for(int x=1; x<=columns; x++){
            if(odd){System.out.print("# ");}
            else{System.out.print(" #");}
        }
        if(odd){odd=false;}
        else{odd=true;}

        System.out.println("");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    checker(4,3);
}

}
```